# Prove the binomial coefficients in the 2^n row are all even

Tags: combinatorics

I want to show that for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$, ${2^m\choose1}, ...,{2^m\choose2^{m}-1}$ are all even.  How does one approach this directly?  I have seen this attempted by showing $(1+x)^{2^m}\equiv {1+x^{2^m}}\pmod 2$ is true for all $m\in \mathbb{N}$ but I don't understand how this implies the statement I want to prove.

Any help is appreciated and please explain any theorem used (not very familiar with combinatorics).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(1+x)^{2^m} = \sum_{k=0}^{2^m} \binom{2^m}k x^k$$ so if that's equivalent to $1 + x^{2^m}$ in characteristic $2$ then all the other coefficients must be even.

Comment: I don't understand the implication from the expressions being congruent mod 2 to the statement that all the other coefficients must be even.  Because I thought we could have an even number of odd coefficient terms, which would result in the expression also being congruent modulo 2.

Comment: $\sum_k a_k x^k \equiv \sum_k b_k x^k \pmod p$ iff $\forall k: a_k \equiv b_k \pmod p$

Comment: Ahh, I see!  Thank you very much for you patience and assistance.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1+x)^2 \equiv 1+x^2\pmod{2},$$
$$(1+x)^4 \equiv (1+x^2)^2 \equiv 1+x^4\pmod{2}, $$
$$(1+x)^8 \equiv (1+x^4)^2 \equiv 1+x^8\pmod{2}, $$
$$\ldots$$
$$ (1+x)^{2^n} \equiv 1+x^{2^n}\pmod{2}. $$
For any $k\in[1,2^n-1]$, the binomial coefficient $\binom{2^n}{k}$ is exactly the coefficient of $x^k$ in the LHS of the last line. 
The RHS gives $\binom{2^n}{k}\equiv 0\pmod{2}$.

---

Alternative approach: we want to prove that $\nu_2\binom{2^n}{k}\geq 1$. By Legendre's theorem
$$ \nu_2\binom{m}{k}=\nu_2\left(\frac{m!}{k!(m-k)!}\right) = \sum_{h\geq 1}\underbrace{\left(\left\lfloor\frac{m}{2^h}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{k}{2^h}\right\rfloor-\left\lfloor\frac{m-k}{2^h}\right\rfloor\right)}_{\geq 0} $$
and if $m=2^n$ the term corresponding to $h=n$ in the last sum equals $1$, so $\nu_2\binom{2^n}{k}\geq 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the proof.  My question is how do you know that if the sum of the coefficients is congruent to 0 modulo 2 that this implies each coefficient must be itself congruent to 0 modulo 2.  That's the part I'm having trouble wrapping my head around.

Comment: @SaranWrap: for instance, on one hand you have $(1+x)^4 = 1+4x+6x^2+4x^3+x^4$. On the other hand you have $(1+x)^4\equiv 1+x^4\pmod{2}$, hence the difference $(1+x)^4-(1+x^4)$ is a polynomial with *even* coefficients. This is exactly the claim.

Comment: Ok so I understand that the sum of the coefficients of $(1+x)^{4} - (1 + x^4)$ must be even, but why does this imply that the polynomial must have even coefficients.  Sorry I feel like I'm just missing something trivial.